# How to calculate % of the target in Excel 2013 Power Pivot's measures?

Tags: excel-2013, powerpivot, dax

Could you please help me to calculate a measure in Excel 2013 Power Pivot that should show what % of a user acquisition target was achieved? Please see the URL below for the images of a desired output and available tables with raw data that are used in Power Pivot and are related through the codes columns. The problematic measures that I am trying to figure out are highlighted in yellow.

http://share.pho.to/9bjSj

The problem is that targets and actual numbers have different granularity levels (actual data per day for every code in a channel vs targets per month for every channel). Also as the table with target values do not have codes I could not figure out how to relate it to other tables.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to create a calculated measure that sums monthly actual data. Now you have monthly actual data that can be compared to monthly targets.

You can hide the monthly actuals if you don't want to show it but only use it in the calculation.

Comment: Thank you. But how do I filter it by Channel at the same time so that I would have Actual # of users per channel (based on codes data)/Target # of users per channel for the same month in one pivot table? Targets are per channel, and each code also belongs to a certain channel.

Comment: Since the target table has no codes in it, it's impossible to relate using codes. How would you now if the target for Yahoo Display Network is for code B or C?

Comment: The target is for the sum of codes of a channel, sorry for not clarifying it from the start. So, for example, the target for Yahoo Display Network is for the sum of codes A, B and C.